# How to fetch the data from web service in the background?

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite

I am fetching data from web service and storing it to SQLite database. The records I'm fetching are more in number so it takes too much time to fetch the data. I want to fetch this data such that while fetching data I can use the app. That is I want to fetch data in the background like we download large files. While downloading we can do the rest of task. How should I implement it in my app?

Answer (score 0):

already there are lot of answers similar to this is available, anyway here is the sample code.
create a innerClass name as MyAsyncClass

```
class MyAsyncClass{
@Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // write your method to fetch data from network

}
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object output) {
    // do what ever you want to do with 'output' data
}
}
```

now you can call this class like this

```
MyAsyncClass myAsyncClass = new MyAsyncClass();
myAsyncClass.execute();
```

and here you can open some new activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourActivityName.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have already used AsncClass. But I want to handle other activities simultaneously while fetching the data.

Comment: according to your question "you want to fetch data in background thread" for this async is good enough, in the mean time you can do what ever you want to do with UI.

Comment: can I switch to other activities while fetching data without stopping fetch operation? And if so where to write code for intent?

Answer (score 0):

you should call  web service from asyncktask which works on background.

```
 @Override  
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {  

                //call your webservice from here;  
                return ;  
            }
```

Comment: I have already used AsncClass. But I want to handle other activities simultaneously while fetching the data.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning I was using my custom Asynctask, but fetch information from a web service was very slow. Now I use Retrofit, and the time is very short. My best advice is that implements Retrofit.

[Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at some helpful tips on [give a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). In this case, merely suggesting Retrofit is not helpful - it would be more helpful to indicate how using Retrofit helps address the problem/question. Alternatively, you could post this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I have already used AsncClass. But I want to handle other activities simultaneously while fetching the data.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla, thank you for your. I'll keep that in mind for my next interventions.